# Docker Rails entrypoint.sh failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, docker

I`m trying to create a docker with rails project:

Here`s my dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.1.2-slim

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    gnupg2 \
    less \
    git \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    libvips42 \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
  BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
  BUNDLE_RETRY=3

RUN gem update --system && gem install bundler

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And here is my entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /usr/src/app/tmp/pids/server.pid

echo "bundle install..."
bundle check || bundle install --jobs 4

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

I`ve also added the rights permissions

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 vitat  staff   274 22 Mar 16:02 entrypoint.sh
```

When I run: **docker-compose up -d** I got this error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./entrypoint.sh": stat ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error says, Docker is unable to find `entrypoint.sh` at the path `./entrypoint.sh` when trying to start your container. The most likely cause is that the `entrypoint.sh` script is not where Docker expects it to be when the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction is executed.

So ensure it’s in the same directory as your Dockerfile and included in your Docker image. Try making the following changes to your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the entrypoint script into the container at /usr/src/app
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Make sure to rebuild your Docker image with `docker-compose build` after making these changes, before running `docker-compose up -d` again.